# DatePicker being truncated in dataTable

Tags: css, angularjs, datatable, datepicker

I have several datePicker in a dataTable , and a vertical scroll on that table.
The issue is that when i open my datepicker, it doesn't "pop outside" the datatable, but does something like this:

[image]

Looking online i found that the solution could be to use the `position:relative` style on the parent of the datePicker , as [stated](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/790#issuecomment-138078454) on the Git page of the datepicker , but it does not seem to work on my case.

Here the directive I use to modify the datepicker :

```
var parent = $(elem).parent();
parent.css('position', 'relative');
var dtp = parent.datetimepicker({
     format: "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss",
      showTodayButton: false,
});
```

Any hint? Did i got something wrong?

EDIT
Here is the HTML of the datatable

```
<div class="table-responsive" >
            <table id="newFornitures" class="table" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'START_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                        <th class="col-order">{{'END_DATE'| translate}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody > 
                    <tr ng-repeat="row in insSupplies">
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="insSupplies[$index].start_date" ng-model="insSupplies[$index].start_date" dateDirective>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="e-ico">today</span>
                                </span>                                     
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="input-group date">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="insSupplies[$index].start_date"  ng-model="insSupplies[$index].end_date" dateDirective>
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="e-ico">today</span>
                                </span>                                     
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

and here are the options of the dataTable :

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withDisplayLength(10)
            .withOption('bFilter', false)
            .withOption('bProcessing', false)
            .withOption('sScrollY', "250px")
            .withOption('sScrollX', false)
            .withLanguage({ "sEmptyTable": "Nessuna fornitura presente","sInfoEmpty" : ""})
            .withOption('bPaginate', false);
```

EDIT 2:

After some debugging I understood that the critical class is the `table-responsive` which has an overflow-y:hidden

Now i tried to remove it, but my dataTable doesn't work without that class, is there something that i can do to override that class without changing the source code?

Comment: You must have your parent `<table>` or any other parent element of datepicker style to `overflow: hidden` you must change it you visible or remove that style. If you have a live link I can suggest an answer.

Comment: @weBer i can provide some snippet of HTML code if that helps

Comment: @weBer I ideted the question with the snippets

Comment: Bro please provide with **CSS**, you issue is created by `CSS style` not `HTML`, its better to provide with a live link or fiddle containing the CSS and HTML. and try changing the `.withOption('sScrollX', false)` to `.withOption('sScrollX', auto)`

Comment: @weBer after some debugging, i edited my question pointing out the proble is the table-responsive class of native bootstrap

Comment: is there a **stylesheet** for your custom style in the webpage.?